# Звание лучший по профессии - как правильно?

Tags: орфография

Сначала идет речь о том, что состоится конкурс "Лучший по профессии".
А после: "Многие поборются за звание лучшего по профессии" (или же так: ...за звание "Лучший по профессии"?)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта верны.

За звание "Лучший по профессии"- более официальное, книжное,за звание лучшего по профессии - бытовое.

Только не так:«За званием «Лучшего по профессии» – в Самару отправятся победители смотра-конкурса профмастерства ООО «РН – Северная нефть» http://www.poranarabotu.ru/news/112. Вот это ошибка:приложение в кавычках не изменяется, это же несогласованное определение.Тогда уж без кавычек и со строчной буквы.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, по-моему, лучше не склонять. *Многие поборются за звание "Лучший по профессии".* Дело в том, что сама по себе фраза "лучший по профессии" звучит довольно коряво, и усугублять её ещё и склонением вряд ли стоит.

Дело в том, что предлог "по" в словосочетании "по профессии" употребляется  в значении указания на предмет или лицо, а также свойство, состояние, при помощи которых характеризуется кто-, что-либо или какой-либо признак. *Брат по матери, учитель по профессии, старший по возрасту и т. д.* Поэтому, например, характеризуя Александра Разенбаума, вполне можно сказать, что он по профессии врач, хотя в больнице он уже десятки лет как не работает (точнее, **работает не по профессии**). То есть, получается, что в сочетании "лучший по профессии" есть 2 признака, но нет того кому они адресованы. Даже фразу "лучший по профессии сталевар" скорее можно понять как лучший человек имеющий профессии сталевар, чем лучший профессионал среди сталеваров.

Понятно, что название конкурса уже устоялось, и не нам его менять, но лично я предпочёл бы дистанцироваться от этой фразы путём отсутствия склонения.

Comment: Лучший в чём? по чему?- оба предлога возможны : лучший в профессии, лучший по профессии.  http://www.lib.ru/DIC/OZHEGOW/ozhegow_p_r.txt ПО-Значение 4. Указывает  круг,  вид деятельности или область распространения  деятельности. Чемпион по шахматам. Исследование по  математике.  Лучший по математике. Лучший по прыжкам в воду. Лучший по всем видам спорта.Лучший по решению задач. Так что  нормальное сочетание. В данном случае рядом  конкурс "Лучший по профессии" и звание "Лучший по профессии" - смотрится как повтор. Думаю, лучше было бы заменить форму на "звание лучшего по профессии"

Comment: @Людмила, дело в том что сама по себе фраза "лучший по профессии" имеет смысла не больше, чем "чемпион по спорту". У Ожегова, заметьте, во всех примерах идёт уточнение сферы деятельности, а слова "профессия" или "спорт", из моего примера, не уточняют ничего.  Без указания конкретной специальности выражение попросту ни о чём, а с данным уточнением воспринимается как значение 9 из того же словаря. Я согласен, что всегда есть лучшие **в** той или иной профессии, но с предлогом "по", выражение по-прежнему видится мне довольно-таки корявым.

Comment: Как вариант возможно ли поступить так: "многие поборются за звание лучшего в своей профессии"?

Comment: @Liana, да, такой вариант вполне возможен.